# Camera is unable to initialize

Tags: camera

This after noon I wanted to take a photo with the camera 8Mpx my Razr i (the large, not the front one) and my phone told me "Camera is Unable to initialize."
The front camera works fine however.

I deleted the cache and data from the "Camera" app and it worked once.
Some hours later, I had the same problem, deleting data changed nothing. I rebooted, no change either.

My phone is modded a lot, I started it in safe mode to avoid starting all my Root apps. Apparently it works, the camera starts up just yet.
I have a lot of Xposed module. The only one that is likely to use the camera is Snapchat. I disabled it and she still did not work.

I don't think I am going to bother uninstalling my applications one by one. I'll flash a clean ROM and test the long term.
I read on a forum that someone had the same problem he had opened his mobile phone and re-tensioned springs that serve as connectors between modules attached to the casing and the motherboard.

Before flashing a new ROM and disassemble it, can someone advise me some tests?
Maybe we can identify the issue before using "the hard way".

In advance, thank you
Titus.

EDIT :
I rectify, in safe mode it does not work either.
Hard issue then I guess ...